# Anaconda installs Cudnn 7.3.1 in environment directory--causes Tensorflow 2.0 to fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I was trying to run some simple `tensorflow-gpu` 2.0 code to execute a convolution on an image. I have an Anaconda environment on `ubuntu` 18.04x64 with python 3.6.8.

The error seems to be that when installing `tensorflow-gpu`, Anaconda will install an old version of `cudnn-7.3.1` in the packages directory for the `conda` environment. `Tensorflow` is using this old version of `cudnn`, and that is causing a `cudnn` error when running the code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

# Load sample images
china = load_sample_image("china.jpg") / 255
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg") / 255
images = np.array([china, flower])
batch_size, height, width, channels = images.shape

# Create 2 filters
filters = np.zeros(shape=(7, 7, channels, 2), dtype=np.float32)
filters[:, 3, :, 0] = 1  # vertical line
filters[3, :, :, 1] = 1  # horizontal line

outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(images, filters, strides=1, padding="SAME")

plt.imshow(outputs[0, :, :, 1], cmap="gray") # plot 1st image's 2nd feature map
plt.axis("off") # Not shown in the book
plt.show()
```

I try and run this code and I get an error back saying

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328]
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.3.1 but source was
compiled with: 7.4.2.  CuDNN library major and
minor version needs to match or have higher minor
version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If
using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN
```

library. If building from sources, make sure the
   library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version
 specified during compile configuration.

I actually have `cudnn` version 7.6 installed on my computer, so this conflicting `cudnn` 7.3.1 definitely coming from Anaconda. I searched the Anaconda environment directory for "cudnn" and found all of these old versions of the library. There are a bunch of old `tensorflow` versions as well, though those don't seem to be causing any issues.

Any idea how to resolve this? I can literally copy over the correct `cudnn.h` files and such, but I am not sure that would be the best idea. That could destabilize my system if some symbols have changed, etc.

**UPDATE:**

Found a couple of related but distinct issues. The first was about installing multiple versions of `cuda` and `cudnn` on a computer--which is not what I would like to do. But in the post, the user indicates that Anaconda installed version 7.3.1.

[How to use the newest 7.5 cudnn in conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429304/how-to-use-the-newest-7-5-cudnn-in-conda-environment)

**UPDATE 2:**

I had submitted a github issue for this problem to Anaconda. Basically got no response. Seems like they mis-interpreted the issue. Their response was that they don't support `pip` installed wheels for Tensorflow. But I used the `conda` package manager to install tensorflow-2.0 so that is why it seems like they mis-interpreted the issue. But it is there on github.

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8736

Comment: previuosly was it working ? wat versions do you have?

Comment: It was working before when I had tensorflow 1.13 installed. But for some reason with Tensorflow 2.0 I was getting the errors. I posted the work around I used below. It is not the best answer, but did not get any help from Anaconda on this., so had no choice.

Comment: yeah they make forrible versioning stuf fthere. what  cuda version?

Comment: I have `cuda 10.1` and `cudnn 7.6` installed on my computer, but when I use Tensorflow it uses the Anaconda installed versions. So Tensorflow finds `cuda 9.2` and `cudnn 7.3.1` because those are located in the folder for the Anaconda environment.

Comment: try it without anaconda, say if that helps. i cant find ANY working configuration with this stuff

Comment: @user8426627 I agree. I wish these guys would communicate more. Google is pushing everyone to migrate to Tensorflow 2.0 for new stuff. But then Anaconda has not really communicated a clear plan for getting their environments updated for Tensorflow 2.0. I mean I posted a github issue and you can read their response.

Comment: @user8426627 I was able to get things working with Anaconda. What issue are you running into? We can continue in chat if you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194394/discussion-between-krishnab-and-user8426627).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Anaconda just updated their build to include `cudnn` 7.6 and `cudatoolkit` 10.1.168. So this problem should go away now. The simple solution, if you hit this problem, is to activate your environment with

```
conda activate <environment_name>
```

Then update the packages in your environment

```
conda update --all
```

Or you could also update just the individual packages instead of the entire environment.

Comment: could you please share how did you install tensorflow 2 using conda? I just found one way which uses pip!

Comment: Hey @sarii yes the cudnn issues seem fixed now. So you can create a new conda environment with   `conda create -n tfenv anaconda` . Then you can add cudnn and cudatoolkit with `conda install cudnn cudatoolkit`. Finally you can install tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow-gpu-beta==2.0.0-beta1`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a hacky way to get around this. This might work or it might not work for other users, but it did work for me.

I ended up following the suggestion from this blog [post](https://medium.com/@shaolinkhoa/install-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-alpha-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-ubuntu-ced099010b21?fbclid=IwAR1n3qGGmuG_b2Dns3SnnSmmcFYfooLdm292ZpvGJZ9fgwRUzwDxZVU5pak).

https://medium.com/@shaolinkhoa/install-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-alpha-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-ubuntu-ced099010b21?fbclid=IwAR1n3qGGmuG_b2Dns3SnnSmmcFYfooLdm292ZpvGJZ9fgwRUzwDxZVU5pak

The basic idea is that you can go into your Anaconda folder and swap out the old `cudnn` library files for newer files.

The details of how to do this are in the blog post. But here is basically the steps I followed.

1. Install the `numba` package with `conda install numba` in my tensorflow-2.0 environment. Also install the latest `cudatoolkit 10` package with `conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit` .
2. Download the latest version of `cudnn` from nvidia. I used version 7.6
3. unzip the files to a temporary directory.
4. In Ubuntu, I opened up Nautilus file manager to my Anaconda environments folder and searched for `cudnn`. The `cudnn` fields were in both the `/lib` and `/include` directories of my `Tensorflow-2.0` environment.
5. I copied the `cudnn.h` file from the temporary directory o the Anaconda environment `/include` directory.
6. I copied the remaining `cudnn/lib64` library files from the temporary directory, including the files `libcudnn.so, libcudnn.so.7, libcudnn.so.7.6.0, libcudnn_static.a` to the Anaconda environment `/lib` directory.

7.Then I ran the `numba -s` to check that the new library files were recognized by the environment.

After that, I could run my tensorflow-2.0 code and it worked just fine.